# WebSocket connection and HTTP Authentication failed

Tags: node-red

I keep getting

> "Lost connection to server, reconnecting..." Looking at the web
>   browser console shows the following error: WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://192.168.x.xx/admin/comms' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no
>   valid credentials available

I have searched for a solution, but have yet to find one. Which credentials am I missing and where should I put them?

Comment: Please edit the question to include some more information, e.g. what version on Node-RED/NodeJS, have you made any changes to the `settings.js` file e.g. to enable Admin Authentication?